# How to display dynamic child in expandableListView according to the JSON response

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am developing one app where i have implemented one edpandableListview .i display the ExpandableListView as i got JSON response.i got the JSON response so i parsed it and set to ExpandableAdapter

I want to display dynamic child to be displayed in respective group.if there are 2 order in transaction id then there must be 2 child in respective transaction id id group

Comment: Parsing your JSON as a HashMap isntead of an Object is a little confusing. But you can do your check in the `getChildrenCount`, inside it you can do something like this: `if (_listDataHeader.get(groupPosition).equals("TwoChildren") { return 2; } else { return 1; }`.

Comment: i want dynamic value.i dont know is there 2 or more.there may be no of child

Comment: This is where I'm confused, on what basis do you decide the number of children? Do your check in `getChildrenCount` and return the number of children you need.